# ServiceWorker registration failed- DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker:

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, workbox

I have registered a service worker from an external domain namely https://unpkg.com.
I am using ReactJS frontend CRA, and the domain is https://reactjscms.devdigdev.com

However the service worker does not get registered, i keep getting an error message

*ServiceWorker registration failed-  DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://unpkg.com') does not match the current origin ('https://reactjscms.devdigdev.com').*

service -worker.js

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import {
  precacheAndRoute,
  createHandlerBoundToURL,
  cleanupOutdatedCaches,
} from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute, setCatchHandler } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate, CacheFirst } from 'workbox-strategies';
import { staticResourceCache, googleFontsCache } from 'workbox-recipes';
import { CacheableResponsePlugin } from 'workbox-cacheable-response';

declare const self: any;
clientsClaim();
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

cleanupOutdatedCaches();

staticResourceCache();
googleFontsCache();

const pageFallback = 'offline.html';

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(({ request, url }) => {
  if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
    return false;
  }

  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
    return false;
  }

  if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}, createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html'));

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) => request.destination === 'image',
  new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'images-all',
    plugins: [
      new CacheableResponsePlugin({
        statuses: [0, 200],
      }),
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxEntries: 60,
        maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
      }),
    ],
  })
);

registerRoute(
  ({ request }) =>
    request.destination === 'script' || request.destination === 'style',
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'static-resources',
  })
);

self.addEventListener('message', (event: any) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', (event: any) => {
  const files = [pageFallback];

  event.waitUntil(
    self.caches.open('mysite-dynamic').then((cache: any) => cache.addAll(files))
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event: any) => {
  if (
    event.request.method === 'GET' &&
    event.request.url.indexOf('https://javacms.devdigdev.com') !== -1
  ) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches
        .open('mysite-dynamic')
        .then(cache => {
          return fetch(event.request)
            .then(response => {
              cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
              return response;
            })
            .catch(async () => {
              let cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
              if (cachedResponse === undefined) {
                const cache = await caches.open('workbox-offline-fallbacks');
                cachedResponse = await cache.match('offline.html');
              }
              return cachedResponse;
            });
        })
        .catch(async () => {
          console.log('err');
        })
    );
  }
});
const FALLBACK_HTML_URL = 'offline.html';
// const FALLBACK_IMAGE_URL = "/logo.svg";
const FALLBACK_STRATEGY = new CacheFirst();

setCatchHandler(async ({ event }) => {
  switch (event.request.destination) {
    case 'document':
      return FALLBACK_STRATEGY.handle({ event, request: FALLBACK_HTML_URL });

    default:
      // If we don't have a fallback, return an error response.
      return Response.error();
  }
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />
    <title>DevDigital ReactJs CMS</title>

    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js"
      referrerpolicy="origin"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script>
      if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
          navigator.serviceWorker
            .register(
              "https://unpkg.com/react-pwa-sw@latest/dist/react-pwa-sw.cjs.production.min.js",
              { scope: "https://reactjscms.devdigdev.com" }
            )
            .then(
              function (registration) {
                // Registration was successful
                console.log(
                  "ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ",
                  registration.scope
                );
              },
              function (err) {
                // registration failed :(
                console.log("ServiceWorker registration failed- ", err);
              }
            );
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```